# How to display a message when user clicks the play button in audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a little message to the user if it hits the play button, for him to know the song is loading (because there isn't any loading indicator natively in browsers).

I'm not using `preload="auto"` or `"metadata"` because the server was getting too much traffic, and not all users are going to listen to the these audios.

It takes about 5 seconds for the audio to start playing (it seems it has to download at least 1 or 2 Mb of the audio to really start playing), so I wanted this message to be shown while the audio is loading (or the metadata is loading), or at least show this for 5 seconds after the user clicks on the play button and then hide it.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you post more of your code so we can see what your currently doing (and help you create a solution that works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function message()
{
   $('#msg').css({
      "display":"block"
   })
   setTimeout(hide, 5000);
}
function hide()
{
   $('#msg').css({
      "display":"none"
   })
}
```

```css
.msg{
   display:none
}
```

```html
<body>

 <audio controls  onclick="message()">
 <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
   <label id ="msg" class = "msg">Loading Please wait..</label>


</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: And then what? The message keeps showing forever? What about showing this after the user clicks on PLAY?

Comment: I`ve edited the code as you requested. Please check now.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without adding code to the html?

Answer (score 1):

AudioElement fires event *loadstart*, just use it:

```
myAudio.addEventListener("loadstart", function () {
  console.log(‘start loading ...’)
},false);
```

Comment: How do I implement this? Should I make any change on the audio tags?